# не могу запустить итерацию по целому числу,

Tags: python

```
def sum_and_dif():
    summ = 0
    amount = 0
    number = int(input("Введите число: "))
    for numbers in number:
        summ += numbers
        amount += 1

    diff = summ - amount

    print(f'Сумма чисел: {summ}')
    print(f'Количество цифр в числе: {amount}')
    print(f'Разность суммы и количества: {diff}')

while True:
    sum_and_dif()
```

Comment: Потому что итерация - это последовательный проход по какому-то набору объектов. А целое число - это не набор объектов, это один "цельный" (не итерируемый) объект.

Comment: А что должна делать "итерация по целому числу"? Чему должно быть равно numbers в первом проходе, чему во втором и тд?

Comment: "Сумма чисел"? Сумма цифр числа может быть?

Answer (score 2):

Вы наверно хотели так:

```
while True:                            
    summ = 0
    amount = 0
    number = input("Введите число: ")     # пока никакой перевод на целое число
    if not number:                        # то же самое как  if number == ""
        break
    for numbers in number:
        summ += int(numbers)              # только здесь перевод!
        amount += 1

    diff = summ - amount

    print(f'Сумма чисел: {summ}')
    print(f'Количество цифр в числе: {amount}')
    print(f'Разность суммы и количества: {diff}')
```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Ваш цикл бесконечен, никакой команды `break`. Я добавил эту команду, когда юзер не вводит число, а только нажмет на клавиш <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Итерировать возможно *строку чисел,* т.е. цифру после цифры введенного числа. Потому введенное число не переводим на `int`, только эго отдельные цифры.

---

*Примечание:*

Вместо имени `numbers` лучше использовать что-то друхое, например `digit`:

```
    for digit in number:
        summ += int(digit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как целое число это не итерабельный объект. Для работы вашего кода можете использовать функцию range.

Функция range() возвращает объект, создающий последовательность чисел, начинающуюся с 0 (по умолчанию), последовательно увеличивающуюся (по умолчанию на 1) и останавливающуюся перед заданным числом (обязательный параметр)

Вот измененный код:

```
def sum_and_dif():
    summ = 0
    amount = 0
    number = int(input("Введите число: "))
    for numbers in range(number):
        summ += numbers
        amount += 1

    diff = summ - amount

    print(f'Сумма чисел: {summ}')
    print(f'Количество цифр в числе: {amount}')
    print(f'Разность суммы и количества: {diff}')

while True:
    sum_and_dif()
```

Comment: от себя добавлю ссылку на документацию по методу `range()` -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range